# 3D Model Loading in DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx, 3d-meshes

At the moment I am trying to implement fbx model loading in my DirectX 11 code. This is old code I had create for use with DirectX 9 and I'm simply trying to bring it back up to date.

Since I first create the code, the SDK version I used was 2012.2, not autodesk have released 2014.1. With that, I have managed to update all of my code bar one issue; my sdk seems to be missing all of the .lib and .dll files I need.

In my old code I needed add the following dependency:

> fbxsdk-2012.2-mdd.lib

I thought it would be a case of changing it to:

> fbxsdk-2014.1-mdd.lib

But this doesn't work. I've spent all weekend trying to find a solution to this, but can't. Does anyone know what I need to do in order to genereate these dll and .lib files?

I've downloaded all of the different SDK options from autodesk, I've searched for the 2012.2 version of the SDK, but got nothing. Failing that; can anyone recommend a good library. or way to implement 3D model loading into my project?

I've tried looking at AssImp but found it a nuisance to work with. So I would like to avoid if possible.